# How to solve $\int \frac{1}{1-y^2}$ with respect to $y$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I was solving an A Level paper when I came across this question. I tried substitution, but I'm not getting the answer with that. Would appreciate it if someone would help me.

Comment: You're integrating w.r.t. which variable? x? y?. Is y a function of x or time?

Comment: @K.Rmth couldn't figure out the editing, sorry. It's with respect to y.

Comment: [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F(1-x%5E2))? Edit: There's even a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaTB8quINtE) showing it step by step. Awesome!

Comment: @EricS. Yes. That's the one. I didn't understand how they got the answer as I don't have WolframAlpha Pro.

Comment: Victor's answer hints at the technique used in the video I linked you to. I haven't watched the whole video, but I guess it takes you through it step by step :)

Comment: Find would be a much better word than solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Step 1: Factorize the denominator

To compute the integral, you start of by using the third binomial theorem

$$\int \frac{1}{1-y^2}\ \mathrm{d}y = \int \frac{1}{1-y}\frac{1}{1+y}\ \mathrm{d}y$$

---

## Step 2: Partial fractions

Use a technique called [partial fractions](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/partfrac.htm) to write the integrant as $\frac{A}{1-y}+\frac{B}{1+y}$. $A$ and $B$ are calculated as follows

$$\begin{array}[t]{lll} 
  \frac{A}{1-y}+\frac{B}{1+y} & = & \frac{1}{1-y}\frac{1}{1+y}\\
  A(1+y)+B(1-y)               & = & 1\\
  1(A+B)+y(A-B)               & = & 1\cdot 1 + y\cdot 0
\end{array}$$

[Equating coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Equating_coefficients&oldid=645768524) gives you

$$A+B=1,\ A-B = 0 \Rightarrow A = B = 0{,}5$$

---

## Step 3: Substitution

The remaining integral

$$\int \left(\frac{0{,}5}{1-y}+\frac{0{,}5}{1+y}\right) \ \mathrm{d}y$$

can be solved straightforwardly unsing substitutions 
$$u=y-1,\ s=y+1,\ \mathrm{d}u=\mathrm{d}s=\mathrm{d}y$$

and the fact that $\int \frac{1}{x}\ \mathrm{d}x = \ln(|x|)$.

$$\int \left(\frac{0{,}5}{1-y}+\frac{0{,}5}{1+y}\right) \ \mathrm{d}y = \int \frac{0{,}5}{-u}\ \mathrm{d}u+\int \frac{0{,}5}{s} \ \mathrm{d}s $$

$$=-0{,}5\cdot\ln(|u|)+0{,}5\cdot\ln(|s|)=\frac{-\ln(|y-1|)+\ln(|y+1|)}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{1-y^2} = \frac{1}{(1-y)(1+y)}$$

Proceed with partial fractions decomposition.

Comment: The OPprobably has never heard of partial fractions.

Comment: Probably not, but I think enough details have been provided if we take into account the level of skill required to solve this integral.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood David's intention..

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple substition of $y = \tanh{(u)}$ gives

$\displaystyle\int \dfrac{1}{1-y^{2}} \mathrm{d}y = u + C = \tanh^{-1}y + C = \ln{\dfrac{1 + y}{1 - y}} + C$

Notably can also be solved using partial fractions.

Comment: You miss $1/2$ when going from $tanh^{-1}$ to the logarithm.

Comment: -1 "A level"...